# Move transparent image over another transparent image

Tags: c#, controls, transparent

I define `SelecterControl` user control (with transparent image in background) that contain a `Roll` control with transparent image.

I want to move front control over `SelecterControl`.

when do that,  transparent area of `SelecterControl` don't clear.

[image]

My complete code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace TestControl
{
public partial class SelecterControl : UserControl
{
    private Roll roll;

    public SelecterControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("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")));
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackgroundImage != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(BackgroundImage, e.ClipRectangle, e.ClipRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    #region Roll Horizontal Movement

    int strtX;

    private void roll_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        strtX = e.X;
    }

    private void roll_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            roll.Left += e.X - strtX;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Designer generated code

    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(SelecterControl));
        this.roll = new MapControl.Roll();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // roll
        // 
        this.roll.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        //this.roll.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("roll.BackgroundImage")));
        this.roll.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 1);
        this.roll.Name = "roll";
        this.roll.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(13, 18);
        this.roll.TabIndex = 0;
        this.roll.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.roll_MouseDown);
        this.roll.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.roll_MouseMove);
        // 
        // SelecterControl
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        //this.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage")));
        this.Controls.Add(this.roll);
        this.Name = "SelecterControl";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(251, 22);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
}


class Roll : Control
{
    public Roll()
    {
        BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("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")));
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackgroundImage != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(BackgroundImage, e.ClipRectangle, e.ClipRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}
}
```

What is the cause of this problem?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.roll.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(13, 18);
```

That's the core problem in your code, the "roll" control is too small.  When you use the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag in the CreateParams property, you ask Windows to ensure that the window behind your control always paints first.  Which sets the background pixels for your "roll" control so it can just paint its own stuff on top of them.

Trouble is, your roll control is so small that after you moved it, it isn't large enough to overlap the stray pixels that were drawn previously.  They are no longer inside the roll control window.  So they'll stay there, producing the smearing effect you see.

The only way to avoid this is to make your roll control bigger so it always catches those pixels.  Realistically, as large as the range of the slider.  Problem is, you now lose all benefit of making "roll" a control of its own.  Things like hit testing get complicated, you need to know where the thumb is located to know that the user clicked it.

You might as well create *one* control that draws both the slider and the thumb.  Required code is exactly the same.  And it will be more efficient since you use fewer system resources, windows are expensive objects.

Comment: Thanks for explain problem, it was useful. I change roll size to (80,100) but don't change. also add click event for `SelecterControl` and change roll position with click, but don't change. remove `roll` control and draw it on paint event, but still transparent part of background is smear. try to invalidate parent form to clear background but go to infinite loop.